# Magento onepage blank

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ssl-certificate

We have a black friday sale tomorrow and our site is hosted on bluehost, and is built on Magento CMS and our checkout system is totally blank.

When you click "proceed to checkout" when in the shopping cart, ourwebsitedomain.tld/index.php/checkout/onepage/ is blank.

We recently made some speed changes to our site, and we have undone all of those, to no avail, including editing the htaccess file.

We have tried everything in the Magento forums, nothing's working.

We think it might be a server issue, but unfortunately bluehost is not open today because it's thxgiving, and we cannot backup or restore to an old version of the site because our server is "under maintenance".

We are not sure if it is something we have done, or if it is a server issue.

We send this to bluehost:

// Here are our thoughts:

1. Maybe it's an SSL issue since the URL is https: (oursitedomain.tld/index.php/checkout/onepage/ is the page that will not pull up, won't even redirect). The ssl certificate has not expired, but coudl there be something else wrong with it?
2. Maybe it is another server configuration that we need reset? can you see if there is anything else wrong with the server?
3. We cannot restore to an old backup of the site because the backup and restore version console in cpanel is not working, says the site is under maintenance. At the very least , we need to backup an old version of the site, and get the shopping cart working.. //

Any ideas anyone has would be huge.

Even if there is a workaround, that will be fine. We are trying to bypass onepage with paypal or google, but no luck yet. worse case scenario we will throw a page up saying the checkout is down, the sale is postponed until next week, etc, or for customers to call in.

Comment: What version of Magento do you have? Have you checked error output in `var/log/exception.log` or under `var/report/` ?

Comment: You should enable developer mode for your site. For <= CE 1.3 you can uncomment the Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true) line in index.php - probably should add some IP logic like `if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')` around it.

For other Mage versions, you can adjust the logic around that developer mode call in index.php to work for your IP address. Try and checkout and see if you get an error on onepage. Also, check your server software logs or have Bluehost do it.

Answer (score 1):

A very common (but, alas, not the only) cause of blank pages is PHP's memory limit. Your .htaccess file should have a line like:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Try increasing this value to `512M`. You can confirm what the actual setting is both before and after by creating the following PHP file in your Magento folder.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then simply type the address of this new page (eg. "ourwebsitedomain/phpinfo.php") in your browser and look for "memory_limit".

---

If you want to diagnose the problem correctly then work on eliminating possibilities. Go to "https://ourwebsitedomain/" without the "checkout/onepage" bit and if something shows then you know it's not a problem with SSL.

If the admin section (not cpanel) is working then you have the option of disabling the secure "https" address temporarily. It's not as safe but not required when using paypal, also it's understandable if the alternative is missing out on the biggest shopping day of the year.

Answer (score 1):

PHP pages only go blank (from fatal errors) when display_errors is turned off. Go into /index.php and scroll down near the end of the file. Uncomment the line
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
and let us know what the error you receive is, then we can go from there.